# Inserting note into already installed calender application on android phone

Tags: java, android, mobile

I want to create an application which will have:

- a text field that will take input from the user, and
- a button, which, when clicked, will open a calendar application that is already available in the phone; then, the input text will be added as a note to the selected date.

How can this be done? Is it even possible to do this? If not, how can I display a calendar in my application? I guess this may be a layman's question, but I have just started up with Android programming. Also, I am planning to make the app using HTML, CSS and Javascript. Is it ok to go with it? or is it easier to use only Java and XML files?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Calendar application. Here is an example how to start Dropbox app:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.dropbox.android");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
try
{
    startActivity(intent);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

You should do something similar for Calendar. Maybe you can provide additional params to intent to make your note insterted into specific date.

Comment: Please explain in brief, I am new user.

Answer (score 0):

Go with Java and XML which i prefer, And about HTML,CSS and Javascripte you can use these if you are developing app using `Phonegap`.

About your application you can have customize calendar in android you can find many [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21255922/2811956).